# Trouble logging in as user after changing password

Tags: passwords, centos, passwd

I'm having trouble logging in with a newly-created password on my CentOS system.  I recently installed the continuous integration server Jenkins on CentOS via yum, which created a "jenkins" user.  However, although I seem to be able to change the password, when I try and login with the same password, I repeatedly get a "Permission denied" message.  I know I'm entering the right password b/c I'm just cutting and pasting.  What else do I need to do to activate the user?  Here's what happens …

```
[dalvarado@myserver ~]$ sudo passwd jenkins
Changing password for user jenkins.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: it is based on a dictionary word
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[dalvarado@myserver ~]$ ssh jenkins@localhost
jenkins@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Thanks, -

Comment: What shell is assigned to the `jenkins` user?

Comment: Can you su to jenkins (`su jenkins`)? Also, make sure you are not picking up any trailing whitespace when you copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

What happened was that my user was not part of AllowUsers within the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.  Adding that user and restart sshd healed the pain.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins RPM install creates the dedicated user a no-login user, with `/bin/false` as the default login shell.

To fix this, do

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

and then check this with

```
grep jenkins /etc/passwd
```

which should show bash, not false. After setting the default shell to allow the jenkins user to log in, be sure to assign a password with

```
sudo passwd jenkins
```

and provide the new password at the prompt.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I tried this.  Executing the first command and running grep gave me "jenkins:x:220:498:Jenkins Continuous Build server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash", but after changing the password and then trying to login through "ssh jenkins@localhost," I got the same "Permission denied" error.

Comment: If you're trying to log in from the same machine, then try this:

Comment: The grep response indicates you did enable the jenkins user to log in. If you're trying to log in from the same machine, then try this: logged in as yourself, issue "su - jenkins". You should be prompted for a password, provide the one you assigned the jenkins user. If that works, then initialize the ssh function for the jenkins user by creating a private/public key pair after loggin in ("ssh-keygen"). You can also try connecting to the account from the same machine by using "ssh jenkins@hostname" where hostname is the network name of the current machine given by "hostname".

Comment: Hi, I was able to issue the "su - jenkins" command and successfully enter the password.  I then ran ssh-keygen.  Disappointingly, trying to run "ssh jenkins@hostname" and entering the same password produced the same error as before -- "Permission denied."